# Netbeans Platform: how to use a Frame instead of a TopComponent?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, awt, netbeans-platform

In my project (with the **Netbeans Platform** and **JavaFX**), which is composed by several Tabs (all of them are created subclassing the *TopComponent class*) I'm trying to implement another tab, which should show the screen of a Virtual Machine already running on VirtualBox.

The problem is that the tool I'm using is composed by a *Frame* (from Java awt) as top-level container and, naturally, if I try to add it inside my top component I get an exception because it's not possible to include a top-level container inside another top-level container.

So, this is my question: is it possible to create a new component with the NetBeans Platform without using the TopComponent class? I already tried to do that, but the new tab doesn't appear.

```
@TopComponent.Description(preferredID = "MyTopComponent",
 // iconBase="SET/PATH/TO/ICON/HERE",
 persistenceType = TopComponent.PERSISTENCE_ALWAYS)
@TopComponent.Registration(mode = "editor", openAtStartup = true)
@ActionReference(path = "Menu/Window" /* , position = 333 */ )
@TopComponent.OpenActionRegistration(displayName = "#CTL_MyAction", preferredID = "MyTopComponent")
public class MyTopComponent extends TopComponent {

 /**
  * Logging Facility Instance
  */
 private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTopComponent.class);

 private JFXPanel fxPanel;

 private RDPClient rdpClient;

 private Frame rdpFrame;

 public MyTopComponent() {
  initTopComponent();
  initFXComponent();
  setClientProperties();
 }

 @Override
 public void componentClosed() {
  // TODO add custom code on component closing
 }


 private void initTopComponent() {
  setName(Bundle.CTL_MyTopComponent());
  setToolTipText(Bundle.HINT_MyTopComponent());
 }

 private void setClientProperties() {
  putClientProperty(TopComponent.PROP_CLOSING_DISABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
  putClientProperty(TopComponent.PROP_DRAGGING_DISABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
  putClientProperty(TopComponent.PROP_MAXIMIZATION_DISABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
  putClientProperty(TopComponent.PROP_UNDOCKING_DISABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
 }

 private void initFXComponent() {

  try {
   rdpClient = new RDPClient();
  } catch (RdesktopException ex) {
   Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
  }

  setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
  rdpFrame = rdpClient.getComponent();
  // fxPanel.add(rdpClient.getComponent());
  add(fxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
 }
```

If I try to add the frame inside the JFXPanel it raises an exception. The same happens if I try to add it directly inside the container. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A Frame, by definition, is a top-level window component.  Frames cannot be placed inside another component, other components are placed inside Frames.

If the tool only provides a Frame, it will necessarily be its own window. The only thing you can do with it is set its location, dimensions, show it and hide it, set the title, other framey stuff.